# Property 'content' does not exist on type 'AndroidApplication'

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, nativescript

I am new to `nativescript` app development. And I stucked while implementing broadcast receiver. I searched a lot, but no any solution found. Please can anyone help me?

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as platform from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { android } from "tns-core-modules/application";
//// Register the broadcast receiver
if (app.android) {
    app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(**android.content**.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED,
        function onReceiveCallback(context: android.content.Context, intent: android.content.Intent) {
            var level = intent.getIntExtra(android.os.BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            var scale = intent.getIntExtra(android.os.BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            var percent = (level / scale) * 100.0;
            ////console.log("Battery: " + percent + "%");
        });
}
```

I got this code from `nativescript` official site, But it's saying that "content" in android module is missing..

Please any one help me...

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the *package* `android` with a NativeScript *module*, so remove the line `import { android } from "tns-core-modules/application";`

Comment: Sorry, Its not working. If I remove import then it throws an error **"Cannot find name 'android'"**.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the NativeScript version on your environment.

```
$ tns --version
```

That was a breaking change in the version Nativescript 6.0.0. Earlier versions should access context via

```
app.android.currentContext
```

starting from Nativescript 6.0.0 context is available at:

```
app.android.context
```

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2019-06-28